# How to use JDT to programmatically edit global Javadoc？

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

For example, the code I want to edit is as follows：

```
public class demo {
}
/***/
```

The modified code I want is as follows

```
public class demo {
}
/**default*/
```

I tried to use `ASTParser` to add that Javadoc：

```
ASTParser astParser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
astParser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
astParser.setSource(copy);
astParser.setResolveBindings(true);
astParser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
astParser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
CompilationUnit unit1 = (CompilationUnit) astParser.createAST(null);
unit1.recordModifications();
AST ast = unit1.getAST();
String locations = "default";
TagElement element = ast.newTagElement();
element.setTagName(locations);
for (Object object : unit1.getCommentList()) {
    if (object instanceof Javadoc) {
        Javadoc doc = (Javadoc) object;
        try {
            doc.tags().set(0, element);
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
Document document = new Document(copy.getBuffer().getContents());
TextEdit edits = astRoot.rewrite(document, copy.getJavaProject().getOptions(true));
edits.apply(document);
String javaSource = document.get();
```

But this `javaSource` cannot be applied.

What should I do?